# Need help linking Tensorflow C++ API to C++ project

Tags: c++, tensorflow, dll

I trained a model in Python using Tensorflow and exported it. My wish is to use the model from a c++ program for inference.

I followed [this guide](https://medium.com/vitrox-publication/deep-learning-frameworks-tensorflow-build-from-source-on-windows-python-c-cpu-gpu-d3aa4d0772d8) and I successfully built some libraries using Bazel. The selected Tensorflow version is v4.2.0, without GPU.

The following files were generated in the tensorflow directory:

- tensorflow.dll
- tensorflow.dll.runfiles_manifest
- tf_custom_op_library_additional_deps.dll.gen.def
- tensorflow.dll-2.params
- tensorflow.lib
- tf_custom_op_library_additional_deps.dll.gen.def-0.params
- tensorflow.pdb
- tensorflow.dll.if.exp
- tensorflow.dll.if.lib
- tensorflow_filtered_def_file.def
- includes

In Visual Studio 2019 I added the includes directory for the compiler, and the tensorflow.dll.if.lib and tensorflow.lib  for the linker as inputs. I solved all compile errors and I don't get any linker error. I copied the tensorflow.dll to the directory of the source. The program does not complain about missing dll.

When I run the folowing code:

```cpp
#define NOMINMAX

#include "tensorflow/core/framework/graph.pb.h"
#include "tensorflow/core/public/session.h"
#include "tensorflow/core/public/version.h"

#include <iostream>

int main() {

    std::cout << tf_git_version() << std::endl;
    std::unique_ptr<tensorflow::Session> session(tensorflow::NewSession({}));
    return 0;
}
```

I obtain the following output:

```
unknown

C:\...\x64\Debug\TensorflowTest.exe (process 10236) exited with code -1073741819.
Press any key to close this window . . .
```

One can observe that the functions are not working as expected. The first one prints "unknown" instead of a version number, the second one crashes the application.

After running in the debugger the line before the return statement, the following exception is thrown:

```
Exception thrown at 0x00007FFE6DF4B24B (tensorflow.dll) in TensorflowTest.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0000000000000018.
```

Call stack:

```
    tensorflow.dll!google::protobuf::Map<int,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > >::InnerMap::begin(void)   
    tensorflow.dll!google::protobuf::Map<class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >,int>::clear(void)  
    tensorflow.dll!google::protobuf::Map<class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >,int>::~Map<class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >,int>(void)  
    tensorflow.dll!tensorflow::ConfigProto::~ConfigProto(void)  
    TensorflowTest.exe!tensorflow::SessionOptions::~SessionOptions()
```

Please help me solve this problem.

Comment: _"It is not working"_ is a very vague description of your problem. [Edit] your question and add some relevant information about that please.

Comment: I'm not really sure what is the problem. That is why I'm asking. It seems like it is linked but there is no implementation. I'm not expert in DLLs.

Comment: You don'r even say what your actual problem is! What are the symptoms? How should we know? We can't warch your screen.

Comment: Sorry. The problem is that the functions are not working as expected. The first one prints "unknown" instead of a version number, the second one crashes the application.

Comment: So next: Debugger observations, where exactly does your program stall, what's the call stack at that point, etc., etc.

Comment: Thank you for your guidance. I added the call stack to the question

Answer (score 0):

I forgot that I must run the project in Release mode. After switching to release, the library is working, and the code does not crash.